# Why BIOS isn't recognizing USB drive during installation?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, bios

I have a laptop that I would like to install ubuntu on. This laptop has windows xp on it, but windows wont load. I have ubuntu loaded onto a usb drive, but the computer I am trying to install it on will not recognize the usb drive in the BIOS menu.

Comment: Do you mind adding more information? Like, the kind of Laptop you have? What version of Ubuntu you're installing and how you went about obtaining the live-usb? What do you mean Windows wont load? Is there an issue with Windows or is it hardware related?

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply. The laptop is an old emachines with an AMD athlon processor. The version of ubuntu is 12.04.What do you mean "obtaining the live-usb"? And as far as Windows, When I start up the laptop, after the loading screen for window, a blue creen comes up and says Unmountable boot volume.

Comment: Reason I was asking about the laptop was to see if I could find information on the BIOS settings. Also, how did you load Ubuntu onto the usb drive? And any relevant information you want to add should be put into the body of the question using the edit button. Lastly, I was asking about your Windows distribution because I thought there may have been anissue with the harddrive. But if the windows logo is showing, I doubt that its an hardware issue.

Comment: I should point out that some BIOS don't support booting from usbs...

Comment: Ahhh. Ill add the info into the body. And I followed all of the instructions on the website to get it onto the usb drive. Ive gone into the BIOS menu, and It says "boot from removable device". Would that not be USB?

Comment: Sorry not sure. Do you know the exact model of your laptop? Emachine has numerous series each with quite a bit of different models.

Comment: M6810. And I appreciate you helping

Comment: It alo wont let me boot from disk drive so i guess it could be something to do with my mobo.

Comment: Sorry, tried checking emachine's website for documentation. That failed miserably. Google search turned up [this](http://forum.notebookreview.com/emachines/502926-booting-usb-m6810-possibly-dead-hdd.html) someone else with _identical_ problems. Only other idea I can think of is trying to boot using a live-cd instead of a live-usb.

Comment: Thanks. But I cant manage to boot from my disk drive.

Answer (score 0):

you may enter the bios and chose the boot device and then save the bios setting and reboot.Though you do not really need to change the boot priority.In fact my samsung laptop always come across this phenomena,it's my solution.It seems that by entering the bios and pretending to change and save the bios setting can make the computer recognizing the usb device.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same problem, answer was that you have to go into the BIOs option about Hard Disks. In mine it saw the USB as a second HDD so I had to change the priority so it would read the USB "Hard Disk" first instead of the actual HDD which it did by default.

Comment: The OP stated that the BIOS menu does't recognize the USB. So changing the boot order won't help...